# php regex to replace spaces in braces including braces

Tags: php, preg-replace-callback

I wonder if it's possible to solve such kind of template parsing using RegEx-es
I have text similar to:

```
'Hello, {{ Na me|{{Surname }}}}. Would you like some drink? {{CoffeePreferred? We have a special discount for coffee}} {{Tea Preferred? We have a special discount for tea}}'
```

First, I need to fix errors in variable names (variables must always come right after braces to special symbol like "?" or "|" or something else could be comma or dot - it means rules can be added in future).

`Na me`, `Tea Preferred` `Surname` are spelling errors of variable names. Also variable names should start with right after curly braces contain no spaces after - otherwise it's also an error.

Then I need to keep text as is.

But **Dear friend**, **We have a special discount for coffee** and **We have a special discount for tea** are simple text.

So my question is how can I replace unnecessary spaces withing underscores in variables and keep them in text? Also I want to make it in as fewer steps as possible (due to performance impact and my texts can take megabytes).

I expect my text to be:

```
'Hello, {{Na_me|{{Surname}}}}. Would you like some drink? {{CoffeePreferred? We have a special discount for coffee}} {{Tea_Preferred? We have a special discount for tea}}'
```

My first step was to extract content of braces:

```
preg_replace_callback(
    '/(\{\{)(.*?)(\}\})/ui',
    function ($matches) {
        echo $matches[2];
});
```

Then I tried to replace spaces by rules described above with no success. I tried to use assertions like `/[\s](?!<=\|)/` and expressions like `(\s(?!\|))|((?!\|)\s)` Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: You say `variables always come right after braces to special symbol like "?" or "|" or something else` what do you mean by `something else`?

Comment: What must be the result for the given example?

Comment: @Toto, `variables always come right after braces` - It's a rule but user can break it and in this case I need to fix it (`trim` works fine for simple templates but when braces include braces it become a problem for me) `something else` means rules can be added or changed in future, for example, exclamation mark can have special meaning - so after it all spaces must be kept, before it must be replaced with underscore. I added a result in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do the job:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback(
    '/\{\{([^|?{}]+)/',
    function ($matches) {
        $ret = trim($matches[1]);
        return preg_replace('/ /', '_', $ret);
    },
    $str
);
```

After that you can remove all the braces:

```
$str = preg_replace('/[{}]+/', '', $str);
```